# Gunicorn Flask Restful API and Flask-Socketio crashes when I bind a host and port to Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn, flask-socketio

This is a bit odd as I have been deploying my Flask apps for over a 2 years now using the same way with minor differences depending on the tech stack. 
When I run my Flask app without specifying a host:port for gunicorn as the following:

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 wsgi:app
```

as mentioned int the documenets [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deployment), it works fine, but my sockets don't, as the Gunicorn server starts at almost a different port everytime, which makes it not possible to specify a fixed port in the frontend. That is why I specify the host and port as the following:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --worker-class eventlet -w 1 wsgi:app
```

I should note that I have also tried other alternatives as:

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 1 wsgi:app
```

What happens here is the app is deployed successfully also when I bind a host and address, but crushes with no logs or errors when  which is really frustrating. What is more frustrating is that it works with no issues on the local host whether I specify an address not. Here is my Heroku logs:

```
2020-05-30T10:32:09.146144+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 37f7668f by user use@email.com
2020-05-30T10:32:09.146144+00:00 app[api]: Release v39 created by user user@emai.com
2020-05-30T10:32:20.484467+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-30 10:32:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-05-30T10:32:20.485325+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-30 10:32:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4)
2020-05-30T10:32:20.485476+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-30 10:32:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
2020-05-30T10:32:20.490925+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-30 10:32:20 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-05-30T10:32:22.886718+00:00 app[web.1]: Server initialized for eventlet.
2020-05-30T10:32:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-30T10:33:17.674322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-30T10:33:18.184411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=langcodex.herokuapp.com request_id=d0742a73-96a0-490e-860b-e0ccda544e0b fwd="41.92.113.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-30T10:33:19.352104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=langcodex.herokuapp.com request_id=8f202689-ee4c-4871-bfe3-ef8f9c34b397 fwd="41.92.113.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my app/**init**.py file:

```
import logging, os
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_seasurf import SeaSurf
from flask_cors import CORS
from config import Config, Development


db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
migrate = Migrate()
mail = Mail()
seasurf = SeaSurf()
socket = SocketIO()
cors = CORS()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    """Construct the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='frontend/build/static', 
        instance_relative_config=True)
    # Application Configuration
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    with app.app_context():
        # Initialize Plugins
        login_manager.init_app(app)
        db.init_app(app)
        mail.init_app(app)
        migrate.init_app(app, db)
        seasurf.init_app(app)
        cors.init_app(app, resources={r'/api/*': {'origins': '*'}})
        socket.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", 
            async_mode='eventlet', 
            engineio_logger=True, 
            logger=True)
        # Initialize Global db
        db.create_all()
        from app.serve_frontend_bp import serve_frontend_bp as serve_frontend_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(serve_frontend_blueprint)
        from app.socket_bp import socket_bp as socket_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(socket_blueprint)
        from app.nlp_bp import nlp_bp as nlp_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(nlp_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/nlp')
        from app.main_bp import main_bp as main_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint, url_prefix='/api')
        from app.errors_bp import errors_bp as errors_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(errors_blueprint)
        # Configute Debugging
        if app.debug or app.testing:

            if app.config['LOG_TO_STDOUT']:
                stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
                stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
                app.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
            else:
                if not os.path.exists('logs'):
                    os.mkdir('logs')
                file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/langandcode.log',
                                                   maxBytes=20480, backupCount=20)
                file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
                    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
                    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
                file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
                app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
            app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            app.logger.info('LanguageandCode startup')
        return app
```

Here is my app structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── auth_bp
│   ├── core
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── email.py
│   ├── errors_bp
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── factory.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── frontend
│   ├── functions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logs
│   ├── main
│   ├── main_bp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── nlp_bp
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── serve_frontend_bp
│   ├── socket_bp
│   └── templates
├── config.py
├── latest.dump
├── logs
│   └── langandcode.log
├── migrations
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── README
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── wsgi.py
```

I hope I really find an answer for this as it doesn't make much sense to me, especially with no logs or errors. I hope there's a work to make the port fixed so as to my sockets work. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so what I added to make this work is essentially using:

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 wsgi:app
```

or

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 wsgi:app
```

interchangeably in the procfile, with one minor modification in my app/**init**.py, in the initialization of the socketio:

```
        socket.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", 
        async_mode='gevent', 
        engineio_logger=True, 
        logger=True, 
        port=8000)
```

I basically added a port of 8000 for the sockets to proxy requests to instead of the Gunicorn port that's unknown to the frontend until the server starts,if that's the case. I still don't know why the server crushes when I specify the host and name, and I hope I find an answer, but I'm glad my app and sockets are working correctly now.

Comment: No, you are incorrect. The `port` argument does not exist for `init_app()` it is ignored. Heroku determines which port you use and puts it in the $PORT variable, this is why each time the app runs on a different port. This is totally fine, because from the client you will connect to your app through the Heroku reverse proxy on ports 80 or 443, regardless of which internal port your app is on.

Comment: @Miguel, thank you for your response. This is awkward it was my guess of why the app finally worked, but after some search it turned out to be not the case as you mentioned.